# How to config clients for a wcf service?

Tags: wcf

I am developing a wcf service .
I have created two dll's one for message contracts and one for service contracts interfaces.
I share these two dll's with server and client.
I am not using AddServiceReference i am using ChannelFactory class to create proxies.
Following is the code which i am using to create client proxies:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(); 
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri   ("http://localhost:8989/HelloService/"));
ChannelFactory<IHello> chanFac = new ChannelFactory<IHello>(binding, endpoint);
IHello clientProxy = chanFac.CreateChannel();
```

Now I have to create the binding and EndpointAddress in the code,what i want that this should come from app.config file , how can i do it so that i don't need to write binding and endpoint everytime in the code....
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an app.config like this (when you use "Add Service Reference" from Visual Studio, VS will typically create this for you automatically - and you just need to tweak it to your needs):

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="UserNameSecurity">
              <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8888/MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="UserNameSecurity" contract="IMyService" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8484/MyService/Mex" 
                      binding="mexTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="" 
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" name="mexNetTcp" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The section and its possible values and subsection are well documented in the WCF configuration.

Alternatively, in VS 2008 SP1, you can use the "WCF Service Configuration Editor" - see it in "Tools > WCF Service Configuration Editor".

[image]

It allows you to visually define and modify your client config settings. Once you've launched it from the Tools menu, after that, you can acutally even right-click on the app.config in your Solution Explorer and launch it from there (using that app.config as its basis).

[image]

Marc