# dynamic changing web service url at runtime in metro app

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How to access the service methods if the service reference url is dynamic?

In my metro application , i give a provision to the  user to enter the url in a textbox , depending upon that i need to connect to that service(so the service url will be changing)

1)How to consume the service methods in my metro app if the service refernce url is changing ?

2)how to access one particular service method in my metro app of many service methods present (how to call that one particular only by passing parameters as input)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see the links below [http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/197520/Dynamically-send-WCF-endpoint-in-Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/197520/Dynamically-send-WCF-endpoint-in-Silverlight) [http://www.decoiled.com/post/2011/02/09/WCF-Client-Change-Endpoint-Address-Dynamically.aspx](http://www.decoiled.com/post/2011/02/09/WCF-Client-Change-Endpoint-Address-Dynamically.aspx) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036308/dynamically-switch-wcf-web-service-reference-url-path-through-config-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036308/dynamically-switch-wcf-web-service-reference-url-path

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke WCF web service dynamically, then please go through the following link.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx.

You can download source code from here from which you can invoke web service.